# How to profile iMessages Extension in Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode-instruments

When I try to profile our iMessage extension in `Instruments` on Simulator, I get this error:

> ... please take the appropriate action to initiate the launch of extensionName.MessagesExtension

[image]

while I already brought iMessage in foreground and the extension is up and running (in simulator).

This works on devices. The question is about simulator.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you are supposed to launch iMessage app here when you see this message. Please let me know if it doesn't resolve this.

Comment: iMessage has been started and the iMessage extension is up and running.

Comment: Did you try doing it on device? I tried it on device and it works for me.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No. I assume it is currently not possible (on Simulator). As nobody answered.

Comment: Not working for me as well. Same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

1. Run your extension using Xcode as usual
2. Open Xcode's  'Show the Debug navigator'
3. It will then show some performance graphics, such as "cpu usage", "memory usage", "network usage", etc. When you click on the memory button, Xcode will show "memory usage detail" on the right
4. Pick the "Profile in Instruments"  in the upper right corner.
5. Click it to show results